# Boost converter Inductor Current

Tags: power-electronics, inductor, electromagnetism, magnetics

In a boost converter during switch on time inductor build magnetic field and during off state magnetic field collapse.My question is during off satte inductor is connected to source voltage,so why not it building magnetic field

?[image]

Comment: This is because \$V_{out}\$ being greater than \$V_{in}\$, the voltage across the inductor reverses and the current decays during the off-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the output voltage.

At the start, when the capacitor is discharged, there will still be a positive voltage across the inductor and the current will continue to build in the inductor during the switch open cycle.

When the output capacitor voltage reaches the same level as the supply voltage the voltage across the inductor will be zero during the off cycle. After that the voltage on the capacitor will be greater than the supply voltage. From then on the inductor loses it's charge during the off cycle.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[edited to remove dumbness]
The voltage source for the circuit has a zero ohm output impedance (for analysis purposes), so the left side of the inductor is held steady at the source voltage but the inductor's current flows through the voltage source to GND.  Since the left side is clamped at the input voltage, when the right side voltage starts to rise it rises above the input voltage, creating the boost.

Comment: I was just coming back to fix that.  morning brain fade.  oops.  edited.

Answer (score 1):

For the inductor to be charged a voltage has to be present across it.

This voltage is present when the switch is closed. The voltage will be Vin.

When the switch opens the voltage across the inductor changes. If we assume that the diode is ideal and does not drop any voltage then the voltage across the inductor will be Vin - Vout. Note that for a boost converter Vout > Vin.

So the voltage across the inductor when discharging is: Vin - Vout and this has a **negative** value.

When charging the voltage across the inductor is Vin which has a **positive** value.

So it is the change of the voltage across the inductor which determines if it will charge or discharge.